# euclidean geometry books...

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I consider myself poor in plane euclidean geometry. so I need a good geometry book  which contains very good theory, and a collection a large number of solved problems,  and the end of each part.This book also should start from the basic school level theorems till the olympiad level.

Comment: Artofproblemsolving.com followed by AMC, AIME, and USAMO guides should be a good start

Comment: The ArtofProblemSolving Geometry book is what your after

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go straight into Geometry, try "[Introduction to Geometry](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/viewitem.php?item=intro:geometry)" by Richard Rusczyk

If you want to brush up on other math too, try "[The Art of Problem Solving I/II](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/contests.php)" by Sandor Lehoczky and Richard Rusczyk, which has a good amount of geometry.

If you want a book with more theory, try "[Geometry for College Students (Pure and Applied Undergraduate Texts)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847945)" by I. Martin Isaacs.

Your goto site for competition math should be [The Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/). Just get an account on the forums and go to the geometry section and do problems without looking at the answers first, it's a great resource!

Comment: there is nothing that beats "geometry revisited" by coxeter and grietzer.

Comment: @abel, I'll make it a community wiki and you can add it! There you go, feel free to add anything!